# Origin Vagrantfile location from box-embedded Vagrantfile

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a custom box which contains a embedded `Vagrantfile` (let's call it VF1). This file contains a lot of box-specific config / functionality and the target is I should be (and am) able to generate the project `Vagrantfile` (VF2) just with:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "my/box"
end
```

and still get all the functionality (Puppet integration, VirtualBox tweaks, YAML config support, etc). The problem is that I'd like to read files relative to VF2 from VF1. The way I see it, VF2 gets loaded before VF1 and thus, Vagrant should be able to figure out where VF2 is before loading loading VF1. So, how do I access this information?

Now, to me more concrete, I'll start by linking the GH repo where you can see what I'm trying to do: https://github.com/dkarlovi/vagrant-playground

So:

1. my custom box is called `dkarlovi/centos-6.6`
2. it gets embedded with a custom `Vagrantfile`, https://github.com/dkarlovi/vagrant-playground/blob/master/box/_Vagrantfile
3. when installed, that file ends up in `/home/dkarlovi/.vagrant.d/boxes/dkarlovi-VAGRANTSLASH-centos-6.6/1.0.0/virtualbox/include/_Vagrantfile`
4. I create a new Vagrant project in `/home/dkarlovi/Vagrant/project1`, `vagrant init dkarlovi/centos-6.6 --minimal`
5. when running, I can see that the `/home/dkarlovi/Vagrant/project1/Vagrantfile` gets evaluated before `/home/dkarlovi/.vagrant.d/boxes/dkarlovi-VAGRANTSLASH-centos-6.6/1.0.0/virtualbox/include/_Vagrantfile` so I should, in theory, be able to figure out where's the `Vagrantfile` that started it all
6. I'm currently simulating this, see [line 11](https://github.com/dkarlovi/vagrant-playground/blob/master/box/_Vagrantfile#L11) but this does not work if I run vagrant from say `/home/dkarlovi/Vagrant/project1/src`

I'm doing all of this to be able to check for existence of certain files (Puppet related) and turn provisioning on/off so I'd be able to have a full Puppet stack (if files present) or nothing (if not present), my box becomes more versatile and usable (for my usages).

Comment: i dont get what you are asking for. can you provide more information and examples?

Comment: @DaliborKarlović I'm looking for the same thing, could you be able to find it or how did you solve it?

Comment: @madpoet there's still no solution for this AFAIK. I've created a issue which was closed without resolution. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5636